# Using outer() with a multivariable function

Tags: r

Suppose you have a function `f<- function(x,y,z) { ... }`. How would you go about passing a constant to one argument, but letting the other ones vary? In other words, I would like to do something like this:

```
 output <- outer(x,y,f(x,y,z=2))
```

This code doesn't evaluate, but is there a way to do this?

Comment: You know what, I realized I've often been doing this sort of thing with `do.call(lapply, c(expand.grid(x, y), list(f)))`, but `outer` is definatelly better and more readable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
outer(x, y, f, z=2)
```

The arguments after the function are additional arguments to it, see `...` in `?outer`. This syntax is very common in R, the whole `apply` family works the same for instance.

**Update:**

I can't tell exactly what you want to accomplish in your follow up question, but think a solution on this form is probably what you should use.

```
outer(sigma_int, theta_int, function(s,t)
    dmvnorm(y, rep(0, n), y_mat(n, lambda, t, s)))
```

This calculates a variance matrix for each combination of the values in `sigma_int` and `theta_int`, uses that matrix to define a dennsity and evaluates it in the point(s) defined in `y`. I haven't been able to test it though since I don't know the types and dimensions of the variables involved.

Comment: Ah it's so simple, I have much to learn about R I see... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it's simple... once you know it ;)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but what if I have a function which is dependent on another function? For instance, say I have two intervals,  and for each two elements out of these intervals I want to (i) create an associated variance matrix and (ii) calculate the density at this point (a multivariate normal distribution). To create the variance matrix I have a function y_mat(n,lambda,theta,sigma). Given two intervals sigma_int and theta_int, I wanna do something like z <- outer(sigma_int,theta_int,dmvnorm,x=y,mean=rep(0,n),sigma=y_mat(n,lambda,theta,sigma)). Is this possible?

Comment: That's surely possible to do, but I'll have to get back to you later, cause I have to run an errand now.

Comment: I eagerly await your response.

Comment: I can't test your code now, but your interpretation of my question is 100 % accurate. So thanks again! I'd approve the answer again but... I'd just de-approve it.

Answer (score 2):

`outer` (along with the apply family of functions and others) will pass along extra arguments to the functions which they call. However, if you are dealing with a case where this is not supported (`optim` being one example), then you can use the more general approach of currying. To curry a function is to create a new function which has (some of) the variables fixed and therefore has fewer parameters.

```
library("functional")
output <- outer(x,y,Curry(f,z=2))
```