# R: pass args to outer()

Tags: r, combinations, dplyr

```
set.seed(8)
data <- 
  data.frame(A=rnorm(10),
             B=rnorm(10))



fun <- function(df,x,y){
  require(dplyr)
  res <- 
    filter(df,A<x,B>y) %>%
    nrow()
  return(res)
}
```

This work for single values of x and y:

```
fun(x=1,y=0,df=data)
```

I would like to do use outer() (or similar) to do combinations of an x and y but cannot figure out how to pass the df argument. It seems to be the same issue as in here:
[Using outer() with a multivariable function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951034/using-outer-with-a-multivariable-function).
But passing df through `...` does not work:

```
outer(x=c(0,2),y=c(0,2),fun,df=data)
```

What is missing ?

Comment: The first two arguments of `fun` must be your `x` and `y` **and** it must be vectorized with regard to these arguments if you want to use `outer`.

Comment: @Roland: Could you elaborate...'must be vectorized'

Comment: Vectorize(yourFucntion...., vec=c("x", "y"))

Comment: @Legalizelt: That I did not get Im sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vectorized arguments means your function can take vectors as arguments(!).  As @Roland described in the comments, your function needs to be specifically setup to work with `outer`.  So the first two args should be vectorized.  This means that you can pass a vector of arguments for `x` and `y` and the function will be called on each value of the two.  You can use the `Vectorize` function to do this easily.

```
fun <- Vectorize(function(x, y, df){
  require(dplyr)
  res <- 
    filter(df,A<x,B>y) %>%
    nrow()
  return(res)
}, vectorize.args=c("x", "y"))


outer(c(0,1,2), c(-1,0,2), fun, df=data)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    7    3    0
# [2,]    9    5    0
# [3,]    9    5    0
```

Comment: And to get dimnames on the result: `outer(setNames(x,x), setNames(y,y), fun, df=data)`

Comment: Nice, is vec the vectorize.args argument of `Vectorize` ?

Comment: @user3375672 yes, R functions will match arguments with partial matching

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using `cut`:

```
# borrowing the @Colonel's example:
x = c(0,1,2)
y = c(-1,0,2)

library(magrittr)
data %<>% mutate(
  Ag = cut(A,c(-Inf,x,Inf)), 
  Bg = cut(B,c(-Inf,y,Inf))
)

with(data, table(Ag,Bg))
#           Bg
# Ag         (-Inf,-1] (-1,0] (0,2] (2, Inf]
#   (-Inf,0]         1      4     3        0
#   (0,1]            0      0     2        0
#   (1,2]            0      0     0        0
#   (2, Inf]         0      0     0        0
```

This may not match the inequalities the OP is after, but I suspect some variation would do the trick. Note that `x` and `y` have to be sorted for `cut` to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Curry` and `mapply`:

```
library(functional)

df = expand.grid(c(1,2,0),c(-1,2,0))

mapply(Curry(fun, df=data), df[,1],df[,2])
#[1] 9 9 7 0 0 0 5 5 3
```

Comment: mapply is NOT what I want: I need all combinations of x and y, ie a 3x3 matrix (9 results)

Comment: in this case, just give mapply the right arguments ;)

Comment: Anyone? Seems to close in!

Comment: Maybe you want to put the result in a matrix (like `outer` would do)?

Comment: Yes! But I believed outer would do this - if put rightly as in @LegalizeIt's answer